# c++ enforcing namespace compliance

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

Suppose you have a namespace

```
approvedParams {
   std::string s1 = "my_string_input_1";
   std::string s2 = "my_string_input_2";
}
```

Outside the scope of `approvedParams` there exists a function `myfun(std::string parm1)`

Is it possible to constrain `myfun` signature to only accept fields of type `std::string` from the `approvedParams` namespace?

That is:

`myfun("my_string_input_1")` will not compile.

`myfun(approvedParams::s1)`  will compile.

---

I was considering an implementation with `enum`. However I ultimately want use `approvedParams::s1` and `s2` when I am parsing key-value configuration files. `enum` must be of an integral type. I am not interested in adding another unnecessary layer with `map<int,std::string>` to connect the enum integers with `std::string`.

Comment: To my knowledge enums must be of type int. I need s1 and s2 to ultimately contain strings.

Comment: Use the enum value as an index to the string in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *type* of `s1` and `s2` do not carry information about the namespace they were declared in.

You could rather easily wrap a custom type though.

```
namespace approvedParams
{
   struct keytype { std::string val; };
   keytype s1 = { "my_string_input_1" };
   keytype s2 = { "my_string_input_2" };
}

void approvedParams( approvedParams::keytype );
```

Comment: So used to C I forgot you could wrap the values in a namespace :P

Comment: Why are you using `std::string` for the members?

Comment: I like this implementation. Though struct string { std::string val; } seems to misleading. Perhaps...

struct keytype { std::string val; }

Comment: @bartonm I'm easygoing... :)  You have that added benefit of naming your type something more understandable.

Comment: I mean why are you doing `std::string s1 = {..}` and not `keytype s1 = {...}`?

Comment: This doesn't really enforce anything, it just makes it marginally harder to pass unapproved parameters. One still can write `myfun(approvedParams::keytype{"unapproved param"})` and get away with it.

Comment: @syam is correct - this will deter accidental misuse, but if you decide that you need to enforce this rule, you should seek a more robust solution.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Check my answer, it is based on your idea but expands it as to actually enforce its usage. You may find it interesting (and I can use the feedback in case I messed up something). ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create an `enum` of approved parameter values

```
enum approvedParams {
    val1 = 0,
    val2, ...
};
```

And just create an array with the string using these indexes

```
std::string[] approvedParamValues = { "my_string_input_1", ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take at it, reusing @DrewDormann's idea of a wrapper type but in a way that actually **enforces** its usage.

The idea is basically a variant of the named constructor idiom, but only with static variables instead of fully-fledged factory functions (does this pattern have a name?).

```
// Declaration in .h
class ApprovedParam
{
public:
  static const ApprovedParam foo;
  static const ApprovedParam bar;

  const std::string& value() const { return m_value; }

private:
  std::string m_value;

  ApprovedParam(const char* value) : m_value(value) {}
  ApprovedParam(std::string&& value) : m_value(std::move(value)) {}
  ApprovedParam(const std::string& value) : m_value(value) {}

  // IMPORTANT: the user must not be able to default construct an ApprovedParam
  ApprovedParam() = delete;
};

// Definitions in .cpp
const ApprovedParam ApprovedParam::foo = "foo";
const ApprovedParam ApprovedParam::bar = "bar";
```

Now the user can copy/move/assign `ApprovedParam` objects but he has only a limited set of (immutable) instances to choose from and he will not be able to create completely new ones.